# Background task stops after 3 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background

I want to run a background task. for check the network connectivity even the application in background

```
-(void) beginBackgroundUploadTask
{
    isBackGroundRunning = YES;
    if(self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    {
        [self endBackgroundUploadTask];
    }

    self.backgroundTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

        NSLog(@"Background Time Remaining :%f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);

    }];
}

-(void) endBackgroundUploadTask
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask ];
    self. backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}

-(void) initializeUpdateTimer
{
    a= 0;
    [self.updateTimer invalidate];
    self.updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(checkNetWorkStatus)
                                                          userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{

                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.updateTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; //NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
            });

        }
    }];
}
```

I am `initializeUpdateTimer`  function when application comes to background.
The task is automatomatically stops after 3 minutes.
Is it possible to extend the time for 30 minutes.

Comment: You cannot start a timer in the background.

Comment: @matt : Is there any way to check network status from background atleast 30 minutes.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? If your app is in the background, it isn't running and the network status cannot matter to you. If you are trying to do a background upload/download or try to be called in the background to do a network task, there are great ways to do that. But your code isn't it.

Comment: as per my requirement I need to inform the user as a Local pushnotification if the phone internet connection lost after 30 minutes.

Comment: You cannot, unless your app is already running in the background for some other reason. And, as I've already said, this seems a very pointless requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no way to check if Internet is available once your app is suspended, usually iOS suspends apps in 3 mins but it depends on the OS. But theres a hacky way

1. If you need to know that, is your app is awake or not try using silent push notification,
2. if you receive silent push set a local notification for 30 or more and if you receive another silent push notification remove local notification from its schedule,
3. if silent push never arrives let the local notification do its job.

its my way to implement your requirement but its never recommended, neither by me.